# workbench error 10060 while connecting to Mysql AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have set up a mysql RDS instance which accepts connection from anywhere within our organization. I have set up an user for this instance as well.

Few days back user complained that workbench can not connect to this instance and getting the error : Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060

It used to work for him, but all of a sudden it stopped working. Not sure what user has done between when it worked and now. Anyways, I have done the following troubleshooting steps:
1. did telnet 'rds end point' 3306 from this terminal and noticed connection is there
2.I tried to connect to this instance from my machine using workbench, heidisql and mysql cmd prompt utilities...every time it works
3.reset his password (just for trying)[see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvCsM.png), but problem persists

Thoughts? workbench version is 6.1 CE and user is on windows 7

Comment: Did you troubleshoot his machine or yours?

Comment: I troubleshoot his machine making sure he has connectivity to RDS instance by telnet. I also connected from my machine using his credentials to make sure his credentials are valid.

Comment: Issue has been found. Due to a recent network change connectivity to this VPC has been impacted. When I tested the connection, I was using VPN which wasn't impacted...was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

It was a connectivity issue. Connection couldn't reach out to RDS mysql instance due to firewall, although security group was wide open